# How to check if a varchar contains an upper case char in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have another Question comming up, while solving some problems with postgreSQL. Is there any option, to check (in a check statement), if a varchar() contains an upper case character? 
(I want that my table only holds Strings with at least one upper case letter.)
Thats how my table look:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    code varchar(255) not null,
    CHECK ((char_length(code) >= 10) && check for upperCase?)
);
```

Does anyone have a tip how to solve this? 
Regards,
Lukas

Comment: Simply `and code <> lower(code)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure there are at least one non-lower case character:

```
CHECK ((char_length(code) >= 10) and code <> lower(code))
```

Answer (score 3):

One method is a regular expression:

```
CHECK ((char_length(code) >= 10) and code ~ '[A-Z]')
```